# WinDbg: Couldn't resolve error at xyz!abc::func while setting breakpoint

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

I have attached WinDbg to a process.

When I use the command `bp` to set at break point. I get the following error:

```
bp xyz!abc::func
Couldn't resolve error at xyz!abc::func
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You have symbols/a pdb for xyz?

Comment: I do have symbols, someone recently updated the symbol path though after a version upgrade.

Comment: `start    end        module name
4d6c0000 4dc59000   xyz   (export symbols)       C:\Program Files\path to xyz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you did a `lm m xyz` you got

```
start    end      module name 
4d6c0000 4dc59000 xyz (export symbols)      C:\Program Files\path to xyz
```

where the term `export symbols` tells us it has only loaded the "public" functions of the DLL.

To load the private symbols, do

```
.sympath c:\path\to\your\pdb
.symfix+ c:\symbols
.reload /f
ld xyz
```

And then do a `lm m xyz` again. If it still does not show "private symbols", repeat the same with a `!sym noisy` before and it'll tell you specifically what it could or could not load.

Comment: It turns out that path to symbol file were wrong.
I correct them from the file menu and now it works.